# tell firefox to load different URLs in each tab using command line

Tags: firefox, tabs

I know I have already asked this for chrome, but unfortunately there was no solution for it in chrome. Maybe someone could provide a solution for Firefox.
So I am asking again:

Say I have these URLs:
1-> www.google.com
2-> www.bing.com
3-> www.something.com

I want to open them in tabs relative to their numbers:
tab 1-> www.google.com
tab 2-> www.bing.com
tab 3-> www.something.com

and after that I will need to load these 3 other URLs:
1-> www.learn.com
2-> www.somethingelse.com
3-> www.thirdwebsite.com
-----------
I don't want to open new tabs, but I want to load them in the opened tabs as follows:
tab 1-> www.learn.com
tab 2-> www.somethingelse.com
tab 3-> www.thirdwebsite.com

----------
also I want the developer tools to be opened and stay open for these three tabs always.

any solutions?
It would be great if I could do all of the above without bringing Firefox to front. I'd like it to stay at the background.

Comment: you can open URL in Firefox just by typing the URL after firefox, like `Firefox.exe fb.com youtu.be` in command prompt. See the command line list:: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments

Comment: ok, the main problem is not that, please reread it

Comment: To do that, you're probably going to have to write a Selenium project or a Firefox addon.